# How to redistribute content of a 2-d array?

Tags: arrays, clojure

Is there any quick way to convert

```
[["a" "b"] 
 ["c" "d"] 
 ["e" "f"]]
```

to

```
[["a" "c" "e"] 
 ["b" "d" "f"]]
```

Comment: BTW, what have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

```
(use '[clojure.core.matrix])

(let [a [["a" "b"]
         ["c" "d"]
         ["e" "f"]]]
    (transpose a))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that uses variadic `map` (or `mapv`) with `apply`:

```
(apply mapv vector [["a" "b"]
                    ["c" "d"]
                    ["e" "f"]])
=> [["a" "c" "e"] ["b" "d" "f"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(def x [["a" "b"] 
        ["c" "d"] 
        ["e" "f"]] )

(def y [ (mapv first x)
         (mapv second x) ] )  ; or just `map`

(println y)

=> [[a c e] [b d f]]
```

If you want general manipulation of 2D "arrays" (vector of vectors), please see [tupelo.arrays](https://cloojure.github.io/doc/tupelo/tupelo.array.html#var-transpose) (e.g. the `transpose` function).

Answer (score -2):

I don't think there is a "quick" way, since arrays have a fixed length that is assigned to some piece of memory upon initialization. There will have to be an extraction of the data from the current arrays, and then the different sized arrays will have to be initialized and filled with the extracted data. There are various "(un)packaging" functions in many, many programming languages, but you may want to consider using lists when you need  flexible containers: addition or removal of elements in a linked list can be done in O(1) time.